# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Still have problem with java :/
So here is my problem with list :

```
if(listKey.size() == 1){
        k = listKey.get(0);
}else if(listKey.size() > 1){
        for(int q : listKey){
            if(listKey.get(q) == listKey.size()){
                k = listKey.get(0);
                k1 = listKey.get(1);
            }
            else if(listKey.get(q) == listKey.size() -1 ){
                k = listKey.get(q+1);
                k1 = listKey.get(0);

            }
            else if(listKey.get(q) == key && listKey.get(q) != listKey.size()){
                k = listKey.get(q+1);
                k1 = listKey.get(q+2);

            }
        }


}else if(listKey.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("empty");
    }
```

It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at com.server.PeerNode.findReplicas(PeerNode.java:222)
at com.server.PeerNode.printMenu(PeerNode.java:154)
at com.server.PeerNode.run(PeerNode.java:99)
at com.server.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

I think i'm using correctly the List and how to iterate through it! I'm not exceeding the size of the list when i try to get int from it.
Thanks in advance for help

```
Here is my idea: I got a key = 5 

case 1: array {4}... i just want to put 4 into k
case 2: array {4,6}.. i just to want to put k=6 and k1=4
case 3: array {4,6,7}.. i just want to put k=6 and k1=7
```

I know is mess up my code... and also with some erros. Thanks to hugh i fixed it and now works... it's like that now:

```
    if(listKey.size() == 1){
        keyreplica1 = listKey.get(0);

    }else if(listKey.size() > 1){
        listKey.add(key);
        Collections.sort(listKey);
        for (int q=0; q<listKey.size(); q++){
            if(listKey.get(q) == key && listKey.get(q) == listKey.size()){
                keyreplica1 = listKey.get(0);
                keyreplica2 = listKey.get(1);

            }
            else if(listKey.get(q) == key && listKey.get(q) == listKey.size() -1 ){
                keyreplica1 = listKey.get(q+1);
                keyreplica2 = listKey.get(0);

            }
            else if(listKey.get(q) == key && listKey.get(q) != listKey.size()){
                keyreplica1 = listKey.get(q+1);
                keyreplica2 = listKey.get(q+2);

            }
        }

    }else if(listKey.size() == 0){

    }
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what exactly are you trying to do in this snippet?

Comment: For the question the amount code is insufficient  to find what's happening

Comment: Try printing the size of list it will give you `2` and you are acccesing `3` most probalbly here `k = listKey.get(q+1);` giving you the exception.

Comment: Which is the 64th line of your main class? And PeerNode.java is your class or you're using it from some library? If its your class then provide code for that.

Comment: I put a list of numbers into listKey. I sort it, and base on my personal key I check the first and second numbers higher than my key and try to save them into variables. But, If the size of the array is one, I get only one number ( no matter if is higher than me ), if the size is 2 ( i get the 2 number no matters if they are higher than me ).

Comment: as already mentioned: insufficient code snippet.i really don't get what you are trying to do. you iterate over the values of your arrayList and use them as index for accessing your arrayList. is that intentioned?

Comment: what is the `key` variable in the line `listKey.get(q) == key && listKey.get(q) != listKey.size()`

Comment: The exception that you have printed shows that the `Arraylist`'s `get` method is called with a parameter of `3`. So the line cannot be `k = listKey.get(0);` It may be a line where `listKey.get(3)` is used.

Comment: could you explain in words the "Here is my idea:" section

Comment: there are 3 int and one List of int: int key, int k1, int k2 and listKey. Int key a number assigned. I want to put put 1 number into k1 and into k2 from listKey and they must be higher than key if the size of listKey is higher than 2 otherwise if the size of listKey is 1 i just put any number from listKey into k1 and leave k2 empty or if the size of listKey is 2 i want to put these 2 numbers into k1 and k2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is listKey a List of Integer?  I think you're mixing up the keys and values here - if your list has more than one entry, you loop over its values v, try to get the v-th value in the list.
For example, if listKey was {3,4}, this would attempt to find the 3rd value in the list, which would exceed its bounds.

I think using the following loop instead will give you the behaviour you expect:

```
for (int q=0; q<listKeys.size(); q++){
```

Comment: you got the point. Thank you... and thanks to all who tried out to understand me ( sorry )

Comment: @Enrico Ok, I think I've got it - you have a List<Integer> and you want the largest and second largest elements?  If so, this will do it without needing to iterate through the list:
`code`
  Collections.sort(listKey);

  Integer keyReplica1 = null;
  Integer keyReplica2 = null;
  if (listKey.size() == 0) {

  } else if (listKey.size() == 1) {
   keyReplica1 = listKey.get(listKey.size() - 1);
  } else {
   keyReplica1 = listKey.get(listKey.size() - 1);
   keyReplica2 = listKey.get(listKey.size() - 2);
  }
`code`